# login loop sudo problem

Tags: login

I have the same problem. but after succelsfull logging in with ctr+alt+F1 I can't use sudo. I got the message: 
owner of /usr/bin/sudo must be user number 0 and the setuid bit must be set.
Can anyone tel me how i should do this?